# Multiple commands, but not at the same time

Tags: terminal, python

I want to execute 4 different files in the background with python, but not simultaneous. There should be ~5 seconds between each evaluation, but I can't get it to work. I tried:

```
python cmd1 &; sleep 5; python cmd2 &; sleep 5; python cmd3 &; sleep 5; python cmd4 &
```

But only the first file is executed before the rest. The other three are evaluated at the same time. Then I tried with a double ampersand after each `sleep`:

```
python cmd1 &; sleep 5 && python cmd2 &; sleep 5 && python cmd3 &; sleep 5 && python cmd4 &
```

So that each python command would wait until the `sleep` is done, but that didn't work either. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Are you searching for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612371/how-do-i-run-multiple-background-commands-in-bash ?

Comment: @unlink I think so. Adding parenthesis around each command with sleep (and a different amount of seconds) should work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses: `(sleep 5; python cmd1 &); (sleep 10; python cmd2 &)`